# Django NoReverseMatch Error

Tags: django

I'm trying to develop a blog script with Django. But when I want to show post links, I get NoReverseMatch error.

My views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Create your views here.

from .models import Yazi, Yorum, Kategori
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

def Home(request):
    try:
        posts = Yazi.objects.filter(yayinlanmis=True).order_by('-yayinlanma_tarihi')
    except Yazi.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    site = Site.objects.get_current()

    c = RequestContext(request,{
        'posts':posts,
        'site':site
        })
    return render_to_response('Penguencik_Yazilar/yazi_list.html', c)

def Detail(request, slug):
    post = Yazi.objects.get(slug=slug)
    site = Site.objects.get_current()

    c= RequestContext(request,{
        'posts':post,
        'site':site
        })
    return render_to_response('Penguencik_Yazilar/yazi_detail.html',c)
```

Urls.py in application folder.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.Home,name='index'),
    url(r'^/makale/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)$', views.Detail,name='detail'),
)
```

Urls.py in project folder

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('Penguencik_Yazilar.urls',namespace='blog')),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And template code. What am I doing wrong?

```
{% load url from future %}
...
<a href="{% url 'blog:detail' yazi.slug %}">Read</a>
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:detail' yazi.slug %}">Read</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:detail' slug=yazi.slug %}">Read</a>
```

Cause your view expect `slug` keyword here `(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)`.

Comment: @user2091423, and what if you remove `$` from urlconf here: `url(r'^', include('Penguencik_Yazilar.urls', namespace='blog'))` and here `url(r'^makale/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)$', views.Detail,name='detail'),` remove first slash?

Comment: Working now but no address in URL. Just `<a href="//makale/python-ve-django-ile-yepyeni-bir-baslangic">Read</a>` but I want `<a href="http://localhost/makale/python-ve-django-ile-yepyeni-bir-baslangic">Read</a>`

Comment: Ok, I took care of it. Thank you.

Comment: Note that `href="/any-url/path/"` is a relative URL agains your ROOT `/`. So when you deploy your website for example with `www.example.com` domain,  all of your URLs will work properly. And if you want `href="http://localhost/any-url/path` it will target all of your urls to `localhost`.